Fail to connect a kotlin socket.io client to a node.js socket.io server
This is my server code
const express = require('express');
const {createServer} = require('node:http')
const {Server}= require('socket.io');
const {join} = require('node:path');
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

function main (){

const app = express();    
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
    console.log(socket.id);
});

server.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log('server running at port '+PORT);
});

}

main();

and this is my client's code
class Client{
   private lateinit var socket: Socket
    @Synchronized
    fun setSocket(){
        try {
            val option = IO.Options();
            option.transports = arrayOf("websocket");
            socket = IO.socket("http://127.0.0.1:3000", option)
        }catch (e: URISyntaxException){
            println("error when creating socket")
        }
    }
    @Synchronized
    fun getSocket(): Socket {
        return socket
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun establishConnection(){
        try{
            socket.connect()
        }catch (e:Exception){}

    }

    @Synchronized
    fun closeConnection(){
        try {
            socket.disconnect()
        }catch (e:Exception){
        }
    }

}

fun main() {
    val client = Client()
    client.setSocket()
    client.establishConnection()
}

when running the main function i get these exception
GRAVE: Task threw exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:115) at io.socket.engineio.client.HandshakeData.<init>(HandshakeData.java:16) at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onPacket(Socket.java:541) at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.access$1000(Socket.java:36) at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket$5.call(Socket.java:337) at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117) at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onPacket(Transport.java:124) at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onData(Transport.java:116) at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket.access$100(WebSocket.java:23) at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket$1$2.run(WebSocket.java:73) at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:80) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Exception in thread "EventThread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:115) at io.socket.engineio.client.HandshakeData.<init>(HandshakeData.java:16) at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onPacket(Socket.java:541) at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.access$1000(Socket.java:36) at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket$5.call(Socket.java:337) at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117) at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onPacket(Transport.java:124) at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onData(Transport.java:116) at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket.access$100(WebSocket.java:23) at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket$1$2.run(WebSocket.java:73) at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:80) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Thank u in advance, i would be grateful for any help
i have connected to the server from a web client through an html file and everything is ok, the problem happens when trying to conect to the server from a kotlin client. I use the ip addres for localhost ("127.0.0.1:3000") when creating the socket object and then i establish the connection but it seems not to work

I don't think your server support websockets.

You are using socket.io on server side, but seems you are not using socket.io on the client side in your code.
I think That 's why your code works with your html file  but not in this java client code.
As explained in the "What Socket.IO is not" section, the Socket.IO client is not a WebSocket implementation and thus will not be able to establish a connection with a WebSocket server, even with transports: ["websocket"]:
https://socket.io/docs/v4/troubleshooting-connection-issues/#you-are-trying-to-reach-a-plain-websocket-server
